# Hadoop hdfs unable to locate file

Tags: hadoop

Im trying to copy a file to hdfs using the below command. The filename is googlebooks-eng.... etc....

When I try to list the file within hdfs I don't see the filename being listed.What would be the actual filename?

```
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk:~/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -put /home/hadoop-user/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-0 /user/prema
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk:~/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/prema
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup  192403080 2014-11-19 02:43 /user/prema
```

Comment: what is the relation of hibernate with your question?

Comment: @AtillaOzgur: I did not change the headers..its not related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all hadoop dfs utilies follows unix style. Syntax of hadoop dfs -put is

`hadoop dfs -put <source_file>  <destination>`. Here destination can be a directory or a file. In your case /user directory exists but the directory prema doesn't exist, So when you copy files from local to hdfs prema will be used for the name of the file. `googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-0` and `/user/prema` are same file.

If you wanted to persist the file name. You need to delete the existing file and create a new directory /user/prema before copying;

```
bin/hadoop dfs -rm /user/prema;
bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/prema;
bin/hadoop dfs -put /home/hadoop-user/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-0 /user/prema
```

Now you should be able to see the file inside the hdfs directory /user/prema

```
bin/hadoop dfs -rm /user/prema
```